# making tap hold execute a link

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I'm making a mobile website and I'm a newbie. I couldnt get a image linkt load the herf (iOS6).  Im trying to use the j query mobile tap hold event method

how would I invoke a tel herf using this way

```
<a id="phone" herf="tel:2062710041"> <img src="call.gif" width="40" height="39"></a></div>  
<script>
$("phone").on('taphold', 'phone', tapholdHandler());

function tapholdHandler() {
    href = "tel:12062710041";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function tapholdHandler() {
   window.location = "tel:12062710041";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$("phone")` to `$("#phone")`

Example

```
<script>
$("#phone").on('taphold', {duration: 1000}, tapholdHandler());
function tapholdHandler() {
    href = "tel:12062710041";
}
</script>
```